# NSString not getting right string

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, nsstring

I have UITextField and I want to copy NSString from textfield, but NSString not getting value that contains textfield here is screen with UITextField text:[image]

And here is NSString which was copied, and must contain same as UITextField text, but it doesn't :((( : [image]

What is the problem? Please any help..

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you've connected the outlet?  You may also want to actually copy the string value, rather than just have a pointer to it.

Comment: try making sure the textfield resigns first responder before you get the value